# How to make responsive design for ios using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, responsive-design

I am new to ios- objective c. i want to make responsive design for all devices. Now design take static width, so design will affect in small devices. How to make responsive design for all devices.

Comment: Use **size class**,So that u can give compatible UI for all the available devices .

Answer (score 2):

Here is some great tutorial for responsive layout

http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use AutoLayout for UI.